# Eclipse.app with zero bytes size repeatedly appears in ~/Downloads folder

Tags: eclipse

That is pretty much it. I have already deleted the file 3 times. Is this expected?

I am using OS X 10.11.3 java 8 and Mars.2

Thanks!

Comment: No, it is not expected. I don't see anything like that on my Mac.

Comment: Let me see when it happens. It will be difficult because there are a bunch of things going on. I will check who created the file too.

Comment: Ok. By simply opening Mars.2 for RCP causes the file to be created.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.

1. Delete the content of the file 
   /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/p2/pools.info
2. Restart the eclipse

Comment: Thanks! I will try it!

Comment: This solution worked for me. I had to delete two files "pools.info" and "profiles.info". Please refer the following [bug 492658](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=492658).